# What is this form of database called?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm new to databases and I'm thinking of creating one for a website. I started with SQL, but I really am not sure if I'm using the right kind of database.

Here's the problem:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/B4ZypkC.png]

What I have right now is the first option. So that means that, my query looks something like this:

```
user_id      photo_id     photo_url
0            0            abc.jpg
0            1            123.jpg
0            2            lol.png
```

etc.. But to me that seems a little bit inefficient when the database becomes BIG. So the thing I want is the second option shown in the picture. Something like this, then:

```
user_id      photos
0            {abc.jpg, 123.jpg, lol.png}
```

Or something like that:

```
user_id      photo_ids
0            {0, 1, 2}
```

I couldn't find anything like that, I only find the ordinary SQL. Is there anyway to do something like that^ (even if it isn't considered a "database")? If not, why is SQL more efficient for those kinds of situations? How can I make it more efficient?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think storing photos in separate rows is "inefficient"?  That is the type of arrangement SQL is most optimized for.  You will have much more trouble if you try to use comma-separated values in your tables.

Comment: Read up on 3NF. Anyway why it is inefficent

Comment: I think there is a fundamental mis-understanding of databases here. Read about database normalisation and set based operations. What you have shown in your image is a one-to-many relationship between the user and the photos. You essentially want a users table and a photos table with the photos table containing a 'userid' with a foreign key constraint to the userId in the user table.

Comment: can multiple users have same photo ??? I mean if its not their personal photo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your initial approach to having a `user_id, photo_id, photo_url` is correct. This is the normalized relationship that most database management systems use.

The following relationship is called "one to many," as a user can have many photos.

[image]

You may want to go as far as separating the photo details and just providing a reference table between the users and photos.

The reason your second approach is inefficient is because databases are not designed to search  or store multiple values in a single column. While it's possible to store data in this fashion, you shouldn't.

If you wanted to locate a particular photo for a user using your second approach, you would have to search using `LIKE`, which will most likely not make use of any indexes. The process of extracting or listing those photos would also be inefficient.

You can read more about basic database principles [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 2):

Your first example looks like a traditional relational database, where a table stores a single record per row in a standard 1:1 key-value attribute set.  This is how data is stored in RDBMS' like Oracle, MySQL and SQL Server.  Your second example looks more like a document database or NoSQL database, where data is stored in nested data objects (like hashes and arrays).  This is how data is stored in database systems like MongoDB.

There are benefits and costs to storing data in either model.  With relational databases, where data is spread accross multiple tables and linked by keys, it is easy to get at data from multiple angles and aggregate it for multiple purposes.  With document databases, data is typically more difficult to join in single queries, but much faster to retrieve, and also typically formatted for quicker application use.

For your application, the latter (document database model) might be best if you only care about referencing a user's images when you have a user ID.  This would not be ideal for say, querying for all images of category 'profile pic' or for all images uploaded after a certain date.  You could probably accomplish your task with either database type, and choosing the right database will always depend on the application(s) that it will be used for, but as a general rule-of-thumb, relational databases are more flexible and hard to go wrong with.

Answer (score 0):

What you want (having user -> (photo1, photo2, ...)) is kind of an INDEX :

When you execute your request, it will go to the INDEX and fetch the INDEX "user" in the photos table, and get the photo list to fetch. Not all the database will be looked up, it's optimised.

Answer (score -2):

I would do something like
**Users_Table(One User - One Photo)**
With all the column that every user will have. if one user will have only one photo then just add a column in this table with photo_url

**One User Many Photos**
If one User Can have multiple Photos. then create a table separately for photos which contains only UserID from Users_Table and the Photo_ID and Photo_File.

**Many Users Many Photos**
If One Photo can be assigned to multiple users then Create a Separate table for **Photos** Where there are PhotoID and Photo_File. Third Table **User_Photos** which can have UserID from Users_Table and Photo_ID from Photos Table.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really cover the OP's belief that this type of design is inefficient.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO and my answer provides him a detailed design how to go about it. is there anything wrong with that ???

Comment: I would address why your method is better.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO why it isnt ?